# session not destroying tried all the methods

Tags: codeigniter, session

```
public function logout(){
            //$this->session->unset_userdata($data);
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('login_controller');
```

this my controller when i try to logout it let me logged out but when i copy paste login page link in another window it still open admin page it should open login page over there.

Comment: I think sessions are working correctly. Your issue is on your admin controller which is not testing if your session is set or not as it should. Can you provide that part of the code ?

Comment: have you loaded the 'session' library ? is in your database ci_session table?

Answer (score 0):

What link you are pasting?
That code is needed to better understand the issue.